# Django Rest framework: I want my GET response to be a JSON object of links to all files in my media directory on my local machine. How do i do this?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My Project structure:

```
myproject
    --*
    --*
    --media
    --*
    --*
```

I want to allow users to access to my media directory: I want them to be able to read and download all files in my media directory and I want them to be able to write files to my media directory.

How can I accomplish this using Django rest framework?

Assume that there are 2 files in my media directory: I want to return the following JSON object as a response to a GET request:

```
{
    file1: link_to_example1.txt
}
{
    file2: link_to_example2.txt
}
```

How do I do this -- what should my app's model.py, views.py and maybe serializers.py look like?

Comment: How are you modeling these files with Django?

Comment: @bikemule That's part of my question: how do I model a file (for example the file eg1.txt in my media folder)?

Answer (score 0):

We can start with simple thing like this. Every time user upload a file, one record is created in the model. If you plan to add/remove file without using your system, you may need a method to sync the latest folder content with your model's records.

```
class MediaFile(models.Model):
    media_file = models.FileField()
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class MediaFileSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MediaFile
        fields = ('media_file',)

class MediaViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for listing or retrieving MediaList.
    """
    serializer_class = MediaFileSerializer
```

Then you can study how to upload file with [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) and [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#parsers-and-file-uploads).